# Karak: Regent: Using the "Thorn of Darkness" with full inventory

Tags: karak

In the expansion **Regent** of the **Karak** board game, new equipment "the Thorn of Darkness" was introduced.

If you defeat the **giant bat** while all of your 3 equipment slots are occupied, is it possible to loot the **Thorn of Darkness**, immediately use it on another player without dropping one of the other equipment to the floor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put it in a spell slot:

> ### Spells
>
> A player can have a total of three in any combination. Spells are only used once then removed from the game.

Meaning you can't have it as your fourth spell, even momentarily.

Also note your turn ends when you get the spell token.

> ### End of a Turn
>
> A player's turn ends when ANY of the following situations occur:
>
> - All four actions are used.
> - After combat with a monster (no matter the result).
> - After unlocking and collecting a treasure.
> - **After collecting a key, weapon or spell token.**
> - Healing at a healing fountain.